# Show DIV if 2 specific Checkboxes are checked, if only one checked show different DIV

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, show-hide

What I want to achieved is a way to show a div if 2 checkboxes are checked and show something else if only one is checked else if 3 checkboxes are checked show a different div once again.
I'm trying to have a working version of it.... Any help?

Take a look to this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/downloadtaky/FpF7T/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the markup to

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="opzioni" data-grp="vano1gop1" value="van ass obb 1g op1" class="opzioni" />Opzione 1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="opzioni" data-grp="vano1gop2,vano1gop3" value="van ass obb 1g op1" class="opzioni" />Opzione 2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="opzioni" data-grp="vano1gop4" value="van ass obb 1g op1" class="opzioni" />Opzione 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="vano1gop1" class="vano1grp">Hai scelto l'opzione 1</div>
<div id="vano1gop2" class="vano1grp">Hai scelto l'opzione 2</div>
<div id="vano1gop3" class="vano1grp">Hai scelto l'opzione 3</div>
<div id="vano1gop4" class="vano1grp">Hai scelto l'opzione 4</div>
```

and then use the below JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.opzioni').click(function(){
        var checked = $(this).attr("checked");
        var grps = $(this).data("grp").split(",");
        $.each(grps, function(i, value){
            var elem = $("#" + value);
            checked ? elem.show() : elem.hide();
        });
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FpF7T/1/)

Comment: Almost was I thought....but not really and I'm not able to have it working as I would, could you please help me?
In your DEMO if I click on opzione 2 it opens:
Hai scelto l'opzione 2
Hai scelto l'opzione 3

But I would like it to open only Hai scelto l'opzione 2 and if I choose Opzione 1 & Opzione 2 I would like to open:
 Hai scelto l'opzione 4
If Opzione 1 & Opzione 3 Checked:
Show: Hai scelto l'opzione 5
If Opzione 2 & Opzione 3 Checked:
Show: Hai scelto l'opzione 6

Any possible solution with comments so I can understand :-)

Comment: Change the data-grp="vano1gop2,vano1gop3" to comma separated list of items that you want to open when that particular checkbox is checked. So in the demo, second checkbox open vano1gop2 and vano1gop3.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleContent(){
    document.getElementById('divOne').style.display = 
    document.getElementById('divTwo').style.display = 'none';
    if(document.getElementById('firstCheckbox').checked && 
    document.getElementById('secondCheckbox').checked){
            document.getElementById('divOne').style.display = 
            document.getElementById('divTwo').style.display'';
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('firstCheckbox').checked){
        document.getElementById('divOne').style.display = '';
    }
}
```

That should give you a good idea of how this is done. Try using http://jquery.com/ for simple hide/show things, very easy.